# How to fix 'np.object will be defined as the corresponding NumPy scalar' in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm working with [one of the Deep Learning With Python notebooks](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/chapter07_working-with-keras.ipynb) (second edition)

When I run the following code in cell 1 --

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
    layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])
```

I immediately get this error, which I don't know how to fix:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:585: 
FutureWarning: In the future `np.object` will be defined as the corresponding NumPy scalar.
  np.object,
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_1679/4031490511.py in <module>
----> 1 from tensorflow import keras
      2 from tensorflow.keras import layers
      3 
      4 model = keras.Sequential([
      5     layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
```

...
then a series of other import errors, then this:

```
    583     # strings.
    584     types_pb2.DT_STRING:
--> 585         np.object,
    586     types_pb2.DT_COMPLEX64:
    587         np.complex64,

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py in __getattr__(attr)
    303 
    304         if attr in __former_attrs__:
--> 305             raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
    306 
    307         # Importing Tester requires importing all of UnitTest which is not a

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'object'.
`np.object` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `object`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `object` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. 
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
```

I then thought maybe I had an old version of Keras, so I first looked at the Keras changelog at https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases But I couldn't find anything there having to do with numpy or object, so I tried to get the version I'm using from the terminal:

`python3 -c 'import keras; print(keras.__version__)'`

But it immediately gave me the same errors.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What's the version of numpy and keras?

Comment: numpy 1.19.4. keras 2.6.0

Comment: I googled latest version of keras and numpy so have just now updated to 2.6.11  for keras and numpy-1.24.2
But I get the same error -- AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'object' 
I'm doing this in paperspace, btw

Comment: There could be an issue with how you install the tensorflow and keras in your system. Could you please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) and verify if you have followed all the steps properly to install tensorflow and try running your code again.

Answer (score 8):

Try installing `numpy` version 1.23.4 with following command (this worked for me):

```
pip install numpy==1.23.4
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76296861/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Thanks